# java.lang.InternalError Android

Tags: java, android, threadpoolexecutor

I am getting this error, how can I fix it?

```
  java.lang.InternalError: 
  at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate (Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.start (Thread.java:1063)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:920)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:988)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

A user is sending me some info it is about this:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=1
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:298)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1087)
```

Comment: Step 1. Post enough code for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: That not possible, I am getting this error from Play Console errors. It is an app with thousand of lines @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: Looks like your thread pool fails to create a new thread. What is your max thread pool size? How many threads/pools are you trying to create?

Comment: @MattClark how can I check the max thread pool size?

Comment: I am going to up this question, I can't fix it... nobody got this error?

Comment: Could it be that the jvm is shutting down at the moment the thread is trying to be created?

Comment: I only have that information. Play console said nothing more. But a lot of users got this error.

Comment: How can I reproduce your suggestion?

Comment: Start and stop the app a bunch of times?  Swipe it away while it's in the middle of doing a bunch of work?  If you don't have any more details it's going to be tough to repro...

Comment: Are you calling: `public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` somewhere?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073915/java-lang-stringindexoutofboundsexception-error-startendandlength

Comment: @Dahnark are you using `android:ellipsize` anywhere in your app with values other than `end`?

Comment: @BenP. Yeah, a lot of textViews use it

Comment: @Dahnark I'm not super confident, but it's possible that your issue could be similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487427/crashlytics-reporting-multiples-issues-for-textview-makesinglelayout/45490983#45490983

Comment: @BenP. I will check it but I think I am using maxlines

Comment: @Dahnark Have you solved this? I am also getting similar crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception is just saying that someone tried to call `substring(0, 1)` on an empty string. If you look further in the stack trace, is this coming from your code? If so, then simply check to ensure that the string is not empty before calling `substring` on it.

As for the `Thread.nativeCreate`, do you have some indication that it is related to the other `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception? I'll assume not, since you didn't provide any information about their relation. The most likely cause of `ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker` failing is due to resource exhaustion, either running out of memory or running out of permitted threads on the device. Examine how your are obtaining and configuring the `ThreadPoolExecutor` that you are using an check to see if you might be exceeding its `MaximumPoolSize` or `LargestPoolSize` parameters.

Comment: Well, I implemented crashlytics (thanks to @benp. because I could se his thread). In future version I will get more precise reports and I will come here again... because I only have this info at this moment from Play Console (really almost nothing)